# How do I create thick circle in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

How do I make the circle into thickness ... I am a beginner of Inkscape and not sure how to do create like this.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select your circle and give to it the wanted stroke width in the fill and stroke dialog:

[image]

If the fuzziness of your image is essential, use the blur control at the bottom of the same dialog.